# Portable database for winforms app

Tags: database, portable

I'm creating an application that basically has a user log in and will track what they spend their money on, make pie charts and stuff like that.  This is more of a self-use/friends-use fun app, nothing consumer level.

I can't use sqlLite because I'm using the free version of Visual Studios and the licenses don't agree anymore or something like that.

I don't want to store everything in one huge XML/text file or anything like that.  I wouldn't mind having something portable I could lug around with my program (Copy and paste desktop to desktop?) that I could write queries for to get information.

I'm using Visual studio 2015 express and would like for the database to be portable with the program. Also easy to use/install if possible.  (If not, I can deal with a tedious set up)

Comment: What other databases can you not use? Why would SQLite not work - do you need something integrated with Visual Studio?

Comment: I found some answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557632/free-portable-database)